# Probability that at least $3$ light bulbs are defect

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

There is company that produce light bulbs. The rate that they produce defect light bulb is $1$%. What is probability that among $100$ randomly chosen light bulbs there is at least $3$ defect light bulbs? It's with replacement (so when you take a light bulb you put it back again).

I write maths test in next week and there can be question like this.

No sure how this is solve good? We have set of $100$ light bulbs and we take $3$ from the set where we want that all $3$ is defect. Probability that you take a defect light bulb is $1$% this means that

$$\frac{3}{100} \cdot 0.01= 0.0003= 0.03\text{%}$$

Is solution good?

Comment: No...think of this as a binomial process.  each time you draw a bulb you have a $p=.01$ chance of "success".  The probability that there are at least three successes is $1$ minus the probability that there are $0,1$ or $2$ successes.

Comment: No. To be found is $P(X\geq3)=1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)-P(X=2)$ where $X$ has [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Specification) with parameters $n=100$ and $p=0.01$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the solution is not good. The experiment follows the binomial distribution with parameters $n=100$ and $p=0.01$. The probability that out of $n$ lightbulbs $k$ are going to be defective is given by
$$
{n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.
$$
Using the fact that $P(A)=1-P(A^c)$, where $A^c$ is the complement of the event $A$, we can show that the probability to obtain at least $3$ defective light bulbs is given by
$$
1-\sum_{k=0}^2{100\choose k}0.01^k0.99^{n-k}\approx0.07937.
$$