# There are $400$ televisions where exactly $16$ are defect. What is probability..?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> There are in total $400$ televisions where exactly $16$ of these are
>   defect. What's the probability that from $25$ televisions, at most $2$
>   are defect? This experiment is without replacement (this means if you
>   take a television you don't put it back in the set again).

This is other example they can ask in test I write next week.. Not know good solution for it.

You have in total $400$ television and $16$ of them is defect. I calculate probability that $1$ of the $400$ is defect: $$\frac{16}{400}= \frac{1}{25}$$

Now how I understand task, we have $25$ television which is subset of the total $400$ televisions. We need know how many of the $25$ television can be defect and then use binomial formula on it?

How many of $25$ television can be defect? You don't can know because maybe no is defect. Very confused.. : /

Comment: Can you compute the probability that none are defective?

Comment: @lulu We know that a defect have probability $\frac{1}{25}$. We do $1-\frac{1}{25}= \frac{24}{25}= 0.96 = 96$% that none are defective from the total $400$? Ok wait this is with no replacement.. I need other idea.....

Comment: No, that isn't correct.  Go over the solutions you were handed to [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2497972/probability-that-at-least-3-light-bulbs-are-defect) .  This one is different because it is done without replacement (so the binomial distribution is not what you want) but the overall concept is similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A probability space consists of $C^{25}_{400}$ objects. So $|\Omega| = C^{25}_{400}$.

16 tvs are defected, 384 are not.

Let $A$ be an event that satisfies condition in problem. What is its cardinal number?

$$
|A| = C^{24}_{384} \cdot C^{1}_{16} + C^{23}_{384}\cdot C^{2}_{16} + C^{22}_{384} \cdot C^3_{16}
$$

We conclude that probability you want to find is $\frac{|A|}{|\Omega|}$.

It would be an exact answer. But for sure it cannot be calculated easily...

But an answer can be approximated if you use De Moivre–Laplace theorem.

$p$ here is $\frac{16}{400} = 0.04$, $n = 25$. $x_1 = \frac{\mu - np}{\sqrt{npq}} = \frac{0 - 1}{\sqrt{0.96}} \approx -1.0206 $, $x_2 = \frac{2 - 1}{\sqrt{0.96}} = 1.0206$

$$
P(A) \approx \Phi(x_2 - \frac 12) - \Phi(x_1 + \frac 12) \approx 0.4
$$